# What is the best file sizes for html5 video

Tags: html, video

Just trying to work out what the standard aim is for html5 video in sizes, currently I have my videos around this size:

```
WebM - 4.1Mb
MP4 - 4.9Mb
Ogg - 8.1Mb
```

Is this acceptable and would this be affecting the speed of my video as at the moment it seems to be freezing.

Thanks

Comment: They look relatively small to me, but whether that's a good size depends on a lot of factors. What's the pixel size of those videos? How long are they? What are their quality settings? What's the audio format and quality? When you say "it seems to be freezing" what do you mean? Describe the problem in detail. Is it buffering enough? Does your browser freeze when playing? Does it do the same when played back locally (i.e. not from the server)? Which browsers are you testing, and on which hardware? What network connection? You need to give us a lot more information before we can offer much help.

Comment: Ok so they are all 00.16s long. Im testing on Safari, Chrome & Firefox on my Macbook Air. They have been encoded with a high quality but with no audio. The pixel size of the MP4 is 1280x720px, not sure what the WebM and the Ogg are. The browser doesn't freeze, the rest of the site is loading fine just not the video, its freezing and not loading in enough time so the first frame is just showing. I have a carousel of 4 videos autoplaying and on a reel/loop. Each different video has the same sort of file sizes as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your carousel is trying to play the videos before they've loaded enough data (so you're seeing stuttering and freezes).

You'll probably need to look into the javascript [HTMLMediaElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), making sure you don't start automatic playback before the `readyState` reaches `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`.

(By the way, if you need compatibility with older browsers too, have a look at [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/), which gives you the same API, but with a Flash/Silverlight fallback too.)